# Which is the correct way of writing a serial number with a pound (hash) sign instead of the word?

Tags: grammaticality

Should one write "Serial#999" or "Serial #999"?

I haven't found any rules/sources that favour one usage to the other. If I'm trying to say "Serial Number" but want to replace "Number" with the pound (hash) sign — # — does there have to be a space between them, ("Serial #"), or no space, ("Serial#")?

Comment: I'd attach the number sign to the number: Serial #999.

Comment: Hi SHD...welcome to ELU!  Can you please note where you've looked for this information so our users don't have to repeat the search?  Thanks!

Comment: I've searched through a bunch of google search pages, I've asked friends as well. Too many to list/remember...

Comment: You don't. Nobody does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Neither usage is standard**. The number sign is used as as abbreviation for "number" only when it prefixes a number. This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign) gives two examples of appropriate uses:

> a #2 pencil (read: "a number 2 pencil")
>
> symphony #5 (read: "symphony number 5")

I would be confused by either "serial #" or "serial#". If you must abbreviate, I much prefer "serial no."

Comment: "SN" is also used as an abbreviation, but this only makes sense in the context of someone expecting a serial number in the first place (like on a product tag). For more general use, your suggestion of "serial no" would be much better.

Comment: S/N is used by many different manufacturers all around the world.

Comment: Written on the back of a device "SN" is fine. But if you ask a non-tech person "what is the SN of your TV/phone?" they may be confused.